# jQuery to rezise background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm starting with javascript and CSS now, and I'm stuck in a test project.
What I did down bellow I did based on searchs from other sources, so I don't know if anything is exactly on the right spot, probably not.
So, i'm tryng to resize an image according to the window size.
I did it with the header, but can't make it work for my navbar background.

CSS:

```
.menutop {
  background: url('Images/topo1.png') no-repeat top center;
  height: 50px;
  font-family:  'StreamArtsFont';
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: changeColor 30s infinite;
}
```

Script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    function fullscreen(){
  //Header size change
        jQuery('#header').css({
            width: jQuery(window).width(),
            height: jQuery(window).height()
        });
  //Navbar size change
        jQuery(".menutop").css("background-size", 'auto '+jQuery(window).height()+" cover");
    }
```

Basicaly, what I need to do is to change the height value in the background-size element, with the value provided by "jQuery(window).height()", just like I did with the header.
I'm imaging it's something wrong with the "auto" and the jQuery(window).height(), cause when I use only "cover" it works.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-size` only takes 2 values, not 3. And `$(window).height()` will return an integer. You need to append `px` to that string so that it knows what kind of unit you're trying to use.

I'm assuming you want to do this instead.

```
jQuery(".menutop").css('background-size', 'auto '+jQuery(window).height() + 'px');
```

Comment: It worked! hahaha  Thank you!  That clarifies a lot!